# Internal multithread error during variation experiment

Tags: simulation, anylogic

I run a parameter variation experiment that varies five parameters of two levels each to yield 32 iterations. During the run, the error in the attached image occurred.

-When running this design three separated times with no replications in any of them, the error occurred only in one run of the three.

-When adding replications to the run (even as few as two replications) the error always occurs too early in run time.

-My selection for the maximum available memory for the experiment is: 60,000 Mb of the total 46Gb RAM of the device

-Disabling of parallel execution doesn't seem appealing due to the consequent slow run speed; I use material handling library, and it takes around 18 minutes for a single day run time.

[image: Snapshot of the error]

How can I overcome this error?
Thanks

Comment: try uninstall and then reinstall AnyLogic

Comment: I think you need to send this to AnyLogic support - it is an internal error. Also judging by the spelling error in the error message ( occure vs occur) I don't think it is something that occurs often.